# AWS Pull Request does not trigger SNS Notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to set up SNS-Notifications with AWS-CodeCommit. But even selecting the correect events i am getting no Notification to my E-Mail.

I set up SNS-Notifications in my repository settings (settings>notifications>events) including all 11 events as you can see in this Picture: [image]

I got notifications on branch creating, updating, merging and deletion. But i got no notifications at all on creating a Pull Request, on approving the Pull Request or on closing the Pull Request. Any help regarding this issue?